# PHP Update query not receiving variable already defined in page

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Hi I'm trying to update a single field from a HTML form, for some reason one of the session variables I am passing to the update query is not being accepted. I have already echoed the variable in the page so am fairly certain it exists in memory.

NB, I know my code is horrifically insecure but I'm learning PHP and once I've got the basics working Ill go over it and bring it upto best practice standards.

E2A: If I do var_dump($filename); before trying to run the query it returns string(6) "356/18", after the query it returns NULL. I'm not unsetting the variable anywhere so where could it be going!

Here is my form:

```
      <form method="post" action="">
      <p>Your username is:&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['userid'] ?>&nbsp;Your company ID is:&nbsp;<?php echo $companyid['id']?></p>
      <h3>Please enter note for file: <?php echo $filename; ?></h3>
      <table width="200" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <th width="18%" align="right" nowrap>Add Note:&nbsp;</th>
        <td width="82%" nowrap>
            <input type="text" name="note" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="100%" nowrap>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Here is my UPDATE query:

```
     $sql = "UPDATE fields SET Notes =          ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['note']))."') 
        WHERE companyId='".$companyid['id']."' AND fileNumber ='".$filename."'";
    if($result = mysql_query($sql)) { 
        echo "<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>";
        echo $sql;
        echo $filename;
        } else { 
        echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error(); 
        } 
        } else {
```

echoing $sql produces the following:

```
     UPDATE fields SET Notes = ('asdasda') WHERE companyId='11' AND fileNumber =''
```

and here is the bit where I instantiate the POST vars.

```
         include "header.php";
         $checkFiles = "checkFiles.php";
         // Catches form input from previous page and stores it into session variable called filename for future reference;
         $_SESSION['filename']=$_POST['filename'];
         $filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
         //User id stuff from previous page too; 
         $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
         $id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE DXNumber='".$userid."'");
         // Returns pointer so fetch it as an array and insert it into variable $companyid for later use;
         $companyid = mysql_fetch_array($id);
```

Comment: Maybe you are overwriting $_SESSION['filename'] with $_POST['filename']?

Comment: Am posting the variable contents from a previous page, thats just there to catch the contents. Again, if I echo $_SESSION['filename']; prior to the query it shows the correct contents, but if I echo it after the query its blank. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h3>Please enter note for file: <?php echo $filename; ?></h3>
```

Create a input box

```
<input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $filename; ?>"/>
```

Then filename value will be pass to $_POST array

Comment: I already passed the filename value to the $_POST array in a previous page. The instance in the H3 you quoted outputs correctly, its when I use it in a query it shows null value.

Comment: It is available when you load the page at the first time. But after submitting the form your $filename variable does not contains any value since nothing has been assigned to it. try What I have said . if this not works the please let me know

Comment: Hi Rohit this makes sense, I've just tried a var_dump and after submit my variable is indeed cleared. Thanks for your assistance, I'll try your solution again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `session_start()` on the top of each file.

Just do:

```
AND fileNumber ='".$_SESSION[filename]."'";
```

In your update query.

If that doesn't work, make sure that a value for `$_SESSION[filename]` is being set.

Comment: I've done that in header.php, the session variable works if I echo it, just not in the UPDATE query.

Comment: @Funk247 Why don't you try $_SESSION['filename'] instead of $filename?

Comment: Hi Boz, I did, that also didnt work so I went back to $filename

Comment: @Sean That also doesnt work. Its really weird, the <h3> in the form shows the correct value, but the query shows null.